# Check if HTML contains JavaScript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

I need to check if user submitted HTML contains any JavaScript. I'm using PHP for validation.

Comment: Its maybe a better idea to define an accepted subset of html (tags, attributes and contents) and strip anything that is not accepted. It saves some nasty surprises.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to detect the presence of javascript code, or just make sure the code is sanitized/made non-executable?

Comment: Ideally, if it contains any sort of javascript I would throw an error up to the user who submitted the HTML at the submission stage and never submit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be better to take a different approach and use something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to filter out anything that you don't want. I think it would be very difficult to safely remove any possibility of javascript without actually parsing the HTML properly.

Comment: +1 use an existing popular library. HTML parsing is *hard*, using your own hacked-up regex is a recipe for failure. I can't guarantee HTML Purifier is secure (there have been holes in it in the past), but it's going to be way ahead of your first attempt.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to protect yourself against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS), then you should better use a [whitelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) than a [blacklist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist). Because there are too [many aspects you need to consider when looking for XSS attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Just make a list of all HTML tags and attributes you want to allow and remove/escape all other tags/attributes. And for those attributes that can be used for XSS attacks, validate the values to only allow harmless values.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's not all be naive here:

`<script> "<!-- </script> -->"; document.write("hello world"); </script>` (should pass the filters suggested by regexadvice)

filtering-out javascript is a security-critical thing, which means you need to do it thoroughly and properly, not some quick hack.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the script tags as Pawka states using regular expressions.
I found a thread on this [here](http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/45165.aspx).

Basically it's:

```
$list=preg_replace('#<script[^>]*>.*?</script>#is','',$list);
```

Code is from that page, not written by me.

Comment: What about javascript that doesn't need to be in script tags? such as the stuff in 'onclick'?

Comment: In deed, the regex needs to be extended to get all event handlers too. But maybe several expressions would be easier to read... Anyways, this is a good point which forgot to take into account.

Comment: As mentioned above, I think that filter gets owned by putting the end tag in an HTML comment (and I'm sure the real troublemakers have hundreds of other tricks).  At least remove the ? from after the central .*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to scan for `<script>` tags but you'll also need to scan for attributes like `onclick=""` or `onmouseover=""` etc... that can have javascript without the need for the script tags.

Comment: `<img src="javascript:whatever">`